# Map with key only - for contains checking

Tags: java, graph, dictionary

I have to store a *close list* for this I defined a Map -

`Map<Node, Boolean> closeList = new HashMap<Node, Boolean>()`

now for checking whether a node is exist in this map I use -

`boolean binExists = closeList .containsKey(node)`

seems that the `value-boolean` of the map is unnecessary .

Have you any better idea for this check using HashMap mode (O(1)) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) seems to be exactly what you need.

```
Set<Node> closeSet = new HashSet<>();
Node n1 = new Node();
Node n2 = new Node();
closeSet.add(n1);
System.out.println(closeSet.contains(n1)); //true
System.out.println(closeSet.contains(n2)); //false - though depending upon equals/hashcode implementation of Node
```

Even though using a `Set<Node>` looks better than using a `Map<Node, Boolean>`, `java.util.HashSet` is using a `HashMap` internally in it's implementation. If you need an implementation that uses less memory, you could for instance have a look at [this implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Amemoryefficienthashset.htm).

Answer (score 0):

With [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) you can get the following in O(1):

- size
- isEmpty
- get
- set
- iterator
- listIterator

With [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) you can get the following in O(1):

- add
- remove
- contains
- size